# Firefox search from URL bar

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, chromium

Chrome, at least in the nightlies, has a feature that recognizes searchable websites such as wikipedia and Google Images when you start typing their URL, and lets you search them from the URL bar with a quick press of tab. Is there a firefox addon or feature which does about the same thing?

Comment: You mean in addition to the search box upper right in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest: right click on the search bar on the website you want to search, and select "Add a Keyword for this Search..."

More in depth: bookmark the site, go to Bookmarks -> Organize Bookmarks, select the bookmark, click the "more information" triangle at the bottom of the window. Fill in the "Keyword" field with the text you want to use to indicate a search from the URL bar.

Comment: Nice.  So if you created a keyword 'wp' for wikipedia, you could just type 'wp foo' in the firefox search bar & it would run the search.

Comment: Great tip! This is actually better than I expected because it offers more control.